# User sign-up process

Tags: android, ios, mobile

For my app, users are invited by email to join.
Currently, the link in the email is opening the web-browser to a page where the user creates his password. Then, the user has to install the app, open the app, and log in with his email and the password he created.

I am trying to make the process easier. I am thinking that in the invitation email, the link can point to "an app link". I know iOS has "Universal Links". The app will most probably not be installed, so on iOS, it will open the App Store app to install the app.

I am thinking to create the registration process in the app. But the issue is after the user installs and opens the app, the "app link" is lost. 
The "App Store" app does not pass the original link to the app when the user opens the app first time after install.

Without the information from the link, I am not able to know in the app the email for which the user needs to create the password. I could ask the user for email also, but I was hoping not having to ask him about that.

I guess it's the same for Android.

Any thoughts how to make sign-up process easier?

EDIT: I chose a correct answer but to anybody who might be looking for an answer, I don't think Firebase or anyone else has a 100% reliable way of making a connection between the device where the link was clicked and the device where the app is installed. All the libraries are using some accuracy value and asks you to check it in code. If you think about it, it makes sense, because when the link is clicked and gets open (and that can be in any web-browser app) the JS code needs to compute some hash of the device and it will try to compare it to the hash of the device computed by the app's code when app is open after install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Firebase Dynamic Links to achieve this.

Please refer [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/products/dynamic-links/)

Comment: I think this only supports android and person asking the question wants to implement the same thing for iOS and android, so Appsflyer is pretty much useful.

Comment: Please have a visit at that link. Google Firebase Dynamic Links provide support to iOS, Android, Web, C++ and Unity. It is so easy to integrate and work with.

Comment: Thanks @NagarajN it looks like it's what I need. "So if your user installs your app when clicking on a dynamic link, all that information is still available to you, when the user opens up your app for the first time".

Comment: I need to look into Firebase Dynamic Links a bit more to make an opinion.

Comment: In the meantime, do you know how is it able to retain the link you clicked when you  open the first time? Are they running something like a timer in JavaScript which tries to connect to the app? What's the magic?

Comment: I found this article which mentions something about polling from JS https://venturebeat.com/2015/06/17/3-magic-deep-linking-hacks-for-improving-the-customer-experience/  but some actual examples and code could help

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to use Webview for this

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Appsflyer SDK.
Checkout the documentation [https://www.appsflyer.com/blog/app-installation-referral-conversion-tracking/](https://www.appsflyer.com/blog/app-installation-referral-conversion-tracking/%22HERE%22)

Comment: Can you give more details? Otherwise it sounds like you just advertising. Which would still be OK I guess but only if you also provide some useful information. Thanks.

Comment: I am not advertising, I am an indie developer, its just that I have used the same thing for implementing referral feature in my app. You can use the same framework but the for implementing I cant teach you whole thing, thats the thing you have to do it yourself.

Comment: We are here to help you get the solutions for your issues related to code but not to teach you.